# How can I remove children in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

In the following example

http://jsfiddle.net/pDsGF/

I want to remove just class 'child' from class 'parent'.  I have tried

`.remove($('parent').children('child'))`​

But it doesn't work

Comment: `.remove($('parent').children('child'))` is not valid JavaScript. If you'd look at the console, you would see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . `. I suggest you have a look at the examples in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need periods to get elements by class, for one. For two, that syntax isn't correct.

```
$('.parent .child').remove();
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/pDsGF/4/)

Answer (score 14):

Do you want to remove the childs (with a class "child") of parents (with a class "parent")?

```
$('.parent').children('.child').remove();
```

Or simply:

```
$('.parent .child')​.remove()​;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `$('.parent').find('.child').remove();​` http://jsfiddle.net/pDsGF/1/

**Edit:** In case I misunderstood and you wanted to actually remove the class try `$('.parent').find('.child').removeClass('child')`

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick.

```
$('.parent .child').remove();
```

(minitech beat me to it :) )

Comment: Question is worded oddly, but it's the node having class='child' to be removed, not the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

many ways:
if you have no identifier for the child then you can remove child my its position on the parent :

```
var p ='.parrent';//identify the parrent
   $('p').children('1').remove();//remove the child placed in ('1');
```

remove Directly [ if you have a identifier ]

```
$('.parent .child').remove();//it removes child from the parent.
```

if you dont know what the parent is.

```
var selector = '.child';//you must identify ONE child to find its parent

var sP = $(selector).parent();//selecting the parent for this Child

//now removing the Child [identifier = position of child]

$(select).parent().children("5").remove();
```

In case if you have too many child with same class then but the parent is different for all. you can remove the Child also by putting the child class

```
//[._iNote] is the selector for the removing Element Here.
$(select).parent().children("._iNote").remove();
```

This script only remove selected child in the the selected parrent . if there is many child with same identifier then They all will be removed so [???]
in this kind of case you can create custome attr for selecting the element [only for HTML5 ].
example

```
<p data-me="someThing-i-like"> [its a custom attr (data-me="someThing-i-like")] </p>
```

in this case For removing this element,

```
$("[data-me=someThing-i-like]").remove();// will work fine
```

if you have any quistion about this post plz plz plz let me know [ comment ]